# Why is a comma used here instead of a semi-colon?

Tags: commas

I'm doing some khan academy SAT practice and I came across this question. I can't figure out why the answer I chose is incorrect, and the correct answer is correct. I would really appreciate if you guys could help me figure out why. Thanks. The answer I chose was C, and the correct answer was B. This relates to sentence number 7.

[image]

Comment: What colon?????

Comment: sorry semi colon

Comment: @HotLicks do you know the answer?

Comment: Transcribe what's in the picture. Not only is it impossible for people with text readers to understand what's in pictures, but this picture too small in the first place. Anything necessary to your question should be in text. Pictures are fine, but only in *addition* to required text.

Comment: @JasonBassford While it doesn't help people with text readers, you can click on the image to enlarge it and then it will be readable.

Comment: @Barmar Nobody should be required to follow a link in order to understand what is being said. All essential information should be in text in the post itself.

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't disagree with you, I was just pointing out that there's a workaround to your specific complaint that the text is too small. And you don't have to follow a link, the image is loaded here.

Comment: @Barmar Fair enough. I voted to close the question since it was lacking (immediately useful) information in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the choices is really incorrect. They all express the same idea, and they're all grammatical. You didn't post the actual question from the exam, but it seems like it's asking for the *best* wording, not the only correct wording. B is the answer because it's simple and idiomatic, while the other choices are unnecessarily wordy and redundant. A native speaker might use them if they're deliberately trying to drag the sentence out (perhaps to meet a requirement for length of an essay) or seem more erudite.

You don't use a semicolon before "which" because it doesn't introduce an independent clause. It starts a relative clause, and these are normally set off with a comma.